# The two company entities and the two Paypal accounts use the same set of merchant ID, Key, and Secert, or are they separate?

Tags: paypal

I would like to consult a question about system connection, in the enterprise aspect. At present, we have two registered entities, one is the Hong Kong payment entity associated with Shopify, and we have already connected to the Paypal system; the other is the American entity associated with the self-built website, but has not yet connected to the Paypal system. I would like to ask whether our American entities create different accounts when connecting the system, or whether to build different APPs under the previously connected accounts. I hope to get a reply, thank you very much. Do the two company entities and the two Paypal accounts use the same set of merchant IDs, Key, and Secret, or are they separate?
Attached are the relevant screenshots.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD2An.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's a business matter. Where is the money going after being received into a PayPal account? Does the American entity have its own US bank account where it will be withdrawing funds?

If so they should have their own US PayPal account, with its own corresponding APP credentials for processing their payments.

Otherwise, if all the money is going to HK, a single PayPal account can process everything.  Whether you have a single app in that PayPal account, or create additional apps (for processing payments on separate websites, usually), is up to you.

---

A single app and credentials connected to multiple PayPal accounts is not possible, and does not make any sense.